# Frame must be terminated with a null octet error in Jmeter

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, jmeter, stomp, amq

I have to load test a WebSocket on Jmeter. WebSocket has been implemented using Springboot.
I am facing an issue while sending Stomp data on Jmeter while testing. I am framing text appropriately according to stomp frame. This is the CONNECT frame:

```
log.info("Connect PreProcessor");

String con = "CONNECT\n" +       
       "login:${wsToken}\n" +
                   "passcode:admin\n" +
                   "accept-version:1.1,1.0\n" +
                   "heart-beat:0,0\n" +  
                   "\n"+'\0' ;

vars.put("wsStompCon", con);
```

I am making a send request and when I am subscribing to the connection, AMQ establishes a connection, and I get the CONNECTED response. So no issue in connection.
The issue happens when I am sending data as:

```
String User = "SEND\n" +
                    "content-length:39\n" +
                    "destination:/app/chat.newUser\n\n" +
                    "{\"sender\": \"Usr111222\",\"type\":\"JOIN\"}" +
                    '\0' ;

vars.put("wsAddUser", User);
```

I put the var 'wsAddUser' in the send sampler and am sending the data.

I get this error in response sampler:

*ERROR
message:
Frame must be terminated with a null octet
content-length:0*

I am using websocket plugin by Peter Doornbosch mentioned:

https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/

I have changed the encoding to UTF-8 in Jmeter.Properties file as well. I think the issue is due to encoding but I'm not sure. What changes should I do for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like your calculation of the [content-length header](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Header_content-length) is not very correct as `{"sender": "Usr111222","type":"JOIN"}` is 37 octets and `\0` is another octet so it should be 38.
2. It is [not recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts so you need to replace this line:

   ```
   "login:${wsToken}\n" +
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   "login:" + vars.get("wsToken") + "\n" +
   ```

   (as long as it's not a [GStringTemplate](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine))

   where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for more information and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for description of other JMeter API shortcuts available for the JSR223 Test Elements